# extract part of a string using a before and after pattern in R

Tags: r, string, substring

I'd like to extract the characters 120497 and 120542 from the vector below so that I have something like this  `c("120497","120542")`. I think I could perform this task by extracting everything after `"-t"` and before `".html"`

```
data<-c("mies-are-going-straight-to-hell-t120497.html?sid=0e4851bc16db",
"oss-on-wall-street-cryptocurrency-t120542.html?sid=1c1328efb1e39b40123679e173f184a1")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
str_extract(data, "\\d+(?=.html)")

[1] "120497" "120542"
```

If we consider the numbers to be the firsts then:

```
sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", data)

[1] "120497" "120542"
```